# Is there a best practice to deploy multi stack to one server instance only?

Tags: deployment, docker-compose, mean-stack

I have been working on MEAN stack project and intend to make a deployment. To save cost, I'm going to deploy it all on one server with docker-compose.yml (push my project to server and run `docker-compose up -d`) but I'm not sure that it is a best practice in my case. Could everyone please give me any suggestions or other best practices to work in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issues with this. On a single server compose alone should be fine as long as your code is production ready and as long as you have mechanisms in place for load balancing incase you need to scale the services.

I think you only need something like docker-swarm or kubernetes if you are deploying to multiple servers